# Return value in a row where another value in the row is missing from a range

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
BookType    Version
A           2011
A           2012
A           2013
B           2011
B           2012
B           2013
B           2014
C           2011
C           2012
C           2014
D           2011
D           2012
D           2013
D           2014
```

And I want to select BookTypes which do not have a Version for each year between 2011 and 2014. So it would return:

```
A
C
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have a separate table with all book types?

Comment: Yes, I do have a table of BookTypes

Comment: test my edited script.i

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT BookType
FROM BookTypes
EXCEPT
SELECT BookType
FROM YourTable
WHERE Version BETWEEN 2011 AND 2014
GROUP BY BookType
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Version) = 4
```

Comment: This works for me. 
Say I want to check it against a high number of years for Versions like 1911 to 2014. Is there a way to automate the count of 4 in the "(DISTINCT Version) = 4" part? Actually I just say "(DISTINCT Version) =  2014-2011+1"

Comment: Parameterise the start and end then use `@end - @start + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no unique key or primary key consisting of just `BookType` and `Version`, the query using `NOT EXISTS` is a bit long, but would look something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.BookType
FROM   MyTable t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable a
                   WHERE  a.BookType = t.BookType
                   AND    a.Version = 2011)
OR     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable a
                   WHERE  a.BookType = t.BookType
                   AND    a.Version = 2012)
OR     NOT EXISTS...
```

Another way to handle the issue might be to create the table (probably using
common table expressions) and use `EXCEPT`:

```
;WITH Versions AS
(
    SELECT 2011 AS Version
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2012
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2014
),
Missing AS
(
    SELECT t.BookType, v.Version
    FROM   MyTable t, Versions v
    EXCEPT
    SELECT t.BookType, t.Version
    FROM   MyTable t
)
SELECT DISTINCT m.BookType
FROM   Missing m
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the table name is BOOKS here.
A query like this might help.

```
SELECT BookType, 
count(*) FROM BOOKS 
where Version >= 2011 AND Version <= 2014 
GROUP BY 1 HAVING count(*) < 4;
```

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

This should work with all sample data.
Also if there is any missing year between then also it work.

```
    declare @t table(BookType varchar(50),Versions int)
insert into @t VALUES
('A',2011),('A',2012),('A',2013),('B',2011)
,('B',2012),('B',2013),('B',2014),('C',2011),('C',2015)
,('C',2012),('C',2014),('D',2011),('D',2012)
,('D',2013),('D',2014)
declare @startyear int=2011
declare @tillyear int=2014

;With cte1 AS(
select * 
,(Versions-@startyear) rn2
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by booktype order by versions)rn
from @t
)
select booktype from cte1 c1
where not exists(
select c.booktype
from cte1 c
where c.booktype=c1.booktype
group by c.booktype
having max(rn2)=(@tillyear-@startyear)
and min(rn2)=0)
and rn=1
```